# Animate label in Cocos2d and remove it once animation is complete

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a game whereby you have to collect things that fall from the sky.  Upon catching one I would like the score bonus you got for doing it to appear and then slowly move upwards and fade out.

I found out how to fade a label out but not entirely sure how to move it upwards (say 50px) whilst fading it out at the same time?

```
[label runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1f opacity:0.0f]]
```

Also, as I am doing this on the fly, how should I manage memory and delete the label once the animation has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CCSpawn to create set of actions that will be run at the moment you run your spawn action. Or just run two actions one by one. I mean

```
[label runAction: fadeActioin];
[label runAction: moveAction];
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.. How do I manage the memory issue? I.e. do I need to remove the labels once I am finished with them? And how do I do that?

Comment: it depends on different things. if you want to remove any node from the screen after few actions, you can, for example, create CCSequence. It will run actions in it one by one. At the end of this sequence you can use CCCallFunc to create callback, where you can remove your node. or you can make category for node and add method for any CCNode instance, that will remove itself from parent. You can also call it at the end of the sequence of actions with CCCallFunc